# error accessing postgres container from remote host

Tags: postgresql, docker, patroni

I have a postgres docker cluster running in a docker swarm environment with an overlay network. everything looks fine until when I try accessing the created container from a remote host with this command **psql -h -p -U** .

I'm setting up the postgres initialization parameters using an environment variable file that looks like this

```
`# the name of the cluster
PATRONI_SCOPE=pg-test-cluster

# create an admin user on pg init
PATRONI_admin_OPTIONS=createdb, createrole
PATRONI_admin_PASSWORD=admin

# host and port of etcd service
PATRONI_ETCD_HOST=etcd:2379

# location of password file
PATRONI_POSTGRESQL_PGPASS=home/postgres/.pgpass

# address patroni will use to connect to local server
PATRONI_POSTGRESQL_LISTEN=0.0.0.0:5432

# replication user and password
PATRONI_REPLICATION_PASSWORD=abcd
PATRONI_REPLICATION_USERNAME=replicator

# address patroni used to receive incoming api calls
PATRONI_RESTAPI_LISTEN=0.0.0.0:8008

# api basic auth
PATRONI_RESTAPI_PASSWORD=admin
PATRONI_RESTAPI_USERNAME=admin

# patroni needs superuser adminstrate postgres
PATRONI_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD=postgres
PATRONI_SUPERUSER_USERNAME=postgres`
```

The error I get is

```
`psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "10.66.112.29" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5000?`
```

Im exposing port 5000 through patroni rest api for master DB.

Any ideas where I'm missing the point? thanks !

Comment: What is the IP you are trying to connect to? Is that the server where your docker is running? And can you share the initialization command/composer file for how you set it the container up?

Comment: yes the server is the same docker daemon is running. The port I'm exposing is 5000 for the postgres container, I do this using haproxy load balancer then I have a .yml file that I build a docker stack with to start the services. This is the bit that exposes the ports from the .yml file services:

  haproxy:
    image: haproxy:alpine
    ports:
        - "5000:5000"
        - "5001:5001"
        - "8008:8008" .   Port 5001 is for replication and 8008 is used by patroni api for frontend traffic routing.

Comment: Could you share the whole yml and/or other configurations for docker? I suspect the containers have not been linked properly

Comment: kindly use this github link. I use that repo to set up my environment. https://github.com/seocahill/ha-postgres-docker-stack

Comment: Could you try adding a `ports` config to your db containers? Do this like `ports: - 5000` this will only publish that port within the network. Allowing haproxy to access this container.

Comment: when I build the docker stack that uses patroni rest api(which exposes port 5000 and 5001 for all db services to the haproxy load balancer), this is then how I access the DB containers remotely psql -h -p 5000 -d database. Is this close to your suggestion?